# "CAMERA_ERROR (3): The camera device has encountered a serious error" Xamarin.Forms error encounterd

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, camera

I'm coding a cross-platform app using Xamarin.Forms and currently coding `CameraView` using `Xamarin Community Toolkit` and have a problem with the debug output. This is the code for the XAML file and it is a simple camera preview code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Test.CameraPreview"
             
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="True"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid x:Name="cameraGrid">
            <xct:CameraView x:Name="xctCameraView"
                            CaptureMode="Photo"
                            MediaCaptured="MediaCaptured"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                    <Frame CornerRadius="15" x:Name="videoFrame" WidthRequest="48" Padding="7">
                        <Label Text="Video" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" x:Name="videoLabel" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
                    </Frame>
                    <Frame CornerRadius="15" x:Name="pictureFrame" WidthRequest="48" Padding="7">
                        <Label Text="Picture" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" x:Name="pictureLabel" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
                <ImageButton Clicked="CapturePhoto" HeightRequest="120" WidthRequest="120"
                             HorizontalOptions="Center" x:Name="captureBtn" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And this is the part of the back-end file for the XAML file:

```
private void CapturePhoto(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (xctCameraView != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"xctCameraView is not null");
                xctCameraView.Shutter();
                Debug.WriteLine($"camera picture taken");
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayAlert("Error", "Camera view is not available.", "OK");
            }

        }
private void MediaCaptured(object sender, MediaCapturedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (xctCameraView.CaptureMode)
            {
                default:
                case CameraCaptureMode.Default:

                case CameraCaptureMode.Photo:
                    Debug.WriteLine("Photo captured");
                    try
                    {
                        if (e?.Image != null)
                        {
                            var imageSource = (StreamImageSource)e.Image;
                            using (var stream = imageSource.Stream(CancellationToken.None).Result)
                            {
                                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                                {
                                    stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                                    photoData = memoryStream.ToArray();
                                    // Use the byte array 'photoData' as needed
                                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                                    {
                                        Navigation.PushAsync(new EditPostPage(userId, dareTextId, photoData));
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) 
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine($"Camera capture error: {ex}");
                    }
                break;

                case CameraCaptureMode.Video:
                    break;
            }
            
        }
```

The problem is that `CapturePhoto` method works as it takes the picture and the debug statements show in the output. But the code never goes through `MediaCaptured` method. I have a debug statement `Debug.WriteLine("Photo captured");` and it never shows up. Instead right after I take a picture, these errors show up in the output.

```
[0:] camera picture taken
[EGL_emulation] app_time_stats: avg=37.99ms min=2.80ms max=591.87ms count=36
[System.err] android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_ERROR (3): The camera device has encountered a serious error
[System.err]    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.checkIfCameraClosedOrInError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:2429)
[System.err]    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.stopRepeating(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1329)
[System.err]    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.stopRepeating(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:424)
[System.err]    at crc642e1c7a98bdb5c44a.CameraStateListener.n_onError(Native Method)
[System.err]    at crc642e1c7a98bdb5c44a.CameraStateListener.onError(CameraStateListener.java:49)
[System.err]    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.notifyError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1809)
[System.err]    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.$r8$lambda$KBQCqQRdhVVn7uHI9Xdha6OqnsU(Unknown Source:0)
[System.err]    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.accept(Unknown Source:8)
[System.err]    at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.doInvoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:281)
[System.err]    at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.invoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:204)
[System.err]    at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.OmniFunction.run(OmniFunction.java:97)
[System.err]    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
[System.err]    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
[System.err]    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
[System.err]    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
[System.err]    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
[0:] CameraView: Error camera access
ErrorMessage: CAMERA_ERROR (3): The camera device has encountered a serious error
Stacktrace:   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00068] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/obj/Release/JniEnvironment.g.cs:11884 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeAbstractVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0001a] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:47 
  at Android.Hardware.Camera2.CameraCaptureSessionInvoker.StopRepeating () [0x00000] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-33/mcw/Android.Hardware.Camera2.CameraCaptureSession.cs:1452 
  at Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views.CameraFragment.CloseSession () [0x00011] in <6243432aa10f4b63ae8efc1ac5c0cfbc>:0 
  --- End of managed Android.Hardware.Camera2.CameraAccessException stack trace ---
android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_ERROR (3): The camera device has encountered a serious error
    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.checkIfCameraClosedOrInError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:2429)
    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.stopRepeating(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1329)
    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.stopRepeating(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:424)
    at crc642e1c7a98bdb5c44a.CameraStateListener.n_onError(Native Method)
    at crc642e1c7a98bdb5c44a.CameraStateListener.onError(CameraStateListener.java:49)
    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.notifyError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1809)
    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.$r8$lambda$KBQCqQRdhVVn7uHI9Xdha6OqnsU(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.accept(Unknown Source:8)
    at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.doInvoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:281)
    at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.invoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:204)
    at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.OmniFunction.run(OmniFunction.java:97)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem. I tried restarting the app, restarting the emulator device, and even created a new emulator instance with different API but they all had the same error. As for the emulator, I'm using Pixel-5, API 33, Android 13.0.

I tried to look at all the relevant files that might cause the issue like Android Manifest file and all I did in that file is to ask permission for camera, image, and video. I also tried to clear up user data and cache data in the camera in the emulator and that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: You already posted this question today.  Please do not post duplicates